# Winforms navigation bar control - like Explorer Address Bar

Tags: winforms, controls, autocomplete

Can anyone recommend a .NET winforms control that offers similar functionality to the address bar in Windows Explorer, auto-completing file paths?

I'm not too bothered about Vista-style breadcrumbs - quite happy with a simple XP-style textbox-only appearance, but I'd like it to offer auto-complete suggestions based on the file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in ComboBox has an AutoCompleteSource property which can be set to FileSystem.